# Python, how to extend a list based on the value of the element of the list?

Tags: python

I have a list of addresses say

```
addr1=['0x00800d00', 'numb=4', '0x00800d10', '0x00800d20', 'numb=4', '0x00800d30', '0x00800d40', '0x00800e00', '0x00800e04', '0x00800e10', '0x00800e14', '0x00800e18', '0x00800e1c', '0x00800e20', '0x00800e24', '0x00800e28', '0x00800e2c', 'numb=32', '0x00800e30']
```

and I want to extend the list based on the value in `'numb=<x>'`. 
I.e. if `addr1[1]` is `'numb=4'`, then starting from the value of `addr[2]`, I want to fill up the list with four addresses in starting from `addr[2]` as -> `'0x00800d10', '0x00800d14', '0x00800d18', '0x00800d1c'`
and delete the elements with `'numb='`

so addr2 should be like:

```
addr2=['0x00800d00', '0x00800d10', '0x00800d14', '0x00800d18', '0x00800d1c', '0x00800d20', '0x00800d30', '0x00800d34','0x00800d38', '0x00800d3c', '0x00800d40',...... and so on]
```

Comment: What's your question? Where's the code you've written so far?

Comment: Is the distance between new addresses always 4?

Comment: Try to write out how you would do it yourself *manually* in simple steps. Then translate those steps to an appropriate loop that builds up the second list based on what it encounters when enumerating the values in the first list.

Comment: I didn't understood your question, what about num=32, por example? Do you want to remove all num=? What the value after "num=" means?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility:

```
addr2 = []
numb = 1
for addr in addr1:
    if addr.startswith('numb='):
        numb = int(addr[5:])
        continue
    addr_num = int(addr, 0)
    for i in range(numb):
        addr2.append("{0:#0{1}x}".format(addr_num, 10))
        addr_num += 4
    numb = 1
```